# Custom Repartitioning data in pySpark 1.3

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set containing many columns. Column class has values like 1,2,3,4,..10. I want to partition the data so that all the rows with class=i, are on the one single node.
Can I do this in pyspark 1.3? In pyspark 1.6 there is a functionality **(repartition())** for custom partitioning, wherein we can partition the data on the basis of column values. But can we do the same in pyspark 1.3?

Comment: That function exists in 1.3.1: [`rdd.partition`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.repartition)

Comment: But that only allows us to specify number of partitions we want. But let's say I tell this function to make 10 partitions, am I guaranteed that all the data where class=1 will be contained in one single node?

Comment: Are you looking for `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` which allows you to define a partition function.

Comment: Yes, after repartition, all values for a given key will be located on the same partition.